# Admin upload files to app in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, paperclip, carrierwave

I have two models in my application : `Admin` and `User` with the relation `Admin has_many Users`. Now suppose for one `Admin` I have 10 `Users` and each `User` must have a file. The `User` has no upload rights, only the `Admin` can upload files for `Users`. Manually selecting each `User` and uploading files will be cumbersome. How can the `Admin` upload multiple files at once such that the each file gets linked to its respective `User`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name files in a format that would help you get the user information, You can name the file as user_**user_id** format, e.g., user_1, user_2, user_3, etc. In the server side extract the user information from the file name, like for instance if the file name is "user_1", you can split the string and get the user object

```
user_id = file_name.split("_")[-1]
user = User.find(user_id)
```

Hope that makes sense!